# a very simple Perl script needed

Tags: regex, bash-scripting, perl, text-editing

I have the following text file G.txt.
I need a perl command
`perl -e ...`
that would extract all negative entries ending with `Kč`, so that first line it will be
`-107,60`
and last will be `-63,00`

I have tried this:
`perl -e "~=/Kč/" -f G.txt`

```
12 nezaúčtovaných transakcí
Sbalit
5 Kvě Květen
    
    
ALBERT VAM DEKUJE
Platba kartou
    
-107,60 Kč
5 Kvě Květen
    
    
ALBERT VAM DEKUJE
Platba kartou
    
-91,50 Kč
5 Kvě Květen
    
    
GLOBUS BRNO
Platba kartou
    
-78,00 Kč
4 Kvě Květen
    
    
LIDL DEKUJE ZA NAKUP
Platba kartou
    
-29,90 Kč
4 Kvě Květen
    
    
LIDL DEKUJE ZA NAKUP
Platba kartou
    
-37,80 Kč
4 Kvě Květen
    
    
FN BRNO, USTAVNI LEKAR
Platba kartou
    
-63,00 Kč
```

Comment: @Tetsujin Please do not close. I've post an edit to my OQ. I'm quite new here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write:

```sh
perl -lne 'print $1 if /^(-[\d,]+) Kč/' G.txt
```

outputs

```
-107,60
-91,50
-78,00
-29,90
-37,80
-63,00
```

Notes:

- `-n` option to loop over the lines of the file
- `-l` option to auto-handle line endings
- need to actually print the matched text
- `-f` option not needed (I think, unless you actually want to disable executing $Config{sitelib}/sitecustomize.pl at startup)

Comment: Dear Glenn, you have now saved me dozens of minutes exploring `Google`. Thank you so much.